# How to download and install nvdia-340.96 proprietary driver for ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, graphics, proprietary

How to download and install the nvidia-340.96 proprietary driver for Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)?

This is my old original setup. You can see there was the nvidia-340.96 proprietary driver. I lost all of them after `purge nvidia*`.

[image: screenshot of the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates]

I tried to restore them. I followed the instructions at [Install/Upgrade to NVIDIA 340.65 in Ubuntu 15.04 / 14.10 / 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/install-nvidia-340-65-ubuntu-1504/). It seems it only install the open source version.

```
$ apt-cache search nvidia | grep 340
nvidia-340 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.96
nvidia-340-dev - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
libcuda1-340 - NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
nvidia-331-dev - Transitional package for nvidia-340-dev
nvidia-331-updates - Transitional package for nvidia-340
nvidia-331-updates-dev - Transitional package for nvidia-340-dev
nvidia-331-updates-uvm - Transitional package for nvidia-340
nvidia-331-uvm - Transitional package for nvidia-340
nvidia-340-updates - Transitional package for nvidia-340
nvidia-340-updates-dev - Transitional package for nvidia-340-dev
nvidia-340-updates-uvm - Transitional package for nvidia-340-updates
nvidia-340-uvm - Transitional package for nvidia-340
nvidia-opencl-icd-340 - NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
nvidia-libopencl1-331 - Transitional package for nvidia-libopencl1-340
nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates - Transitional package for nvidia-libopencl1-340
nvidia-libopencl1-340 - NVIDIA OpenCL Driver and ICD Loader library
nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates - Transitional package for nvidia-libopencl1-340
nvidia-opencl-icd-331 - Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-340
nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates - Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-340
nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates - Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-340
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the graphical drivers tool.

1. from the launcher, start "Software & Updates"
2. go to "additional drivers" tab
3. after a while, it will show devices, look for "NVIDIA Corp..."
4. set radio button to "Using nvidia binary driver 340.96 ..."
5. press "apply changes" button

Wait for the process to finish, and reboot your computer.

Comment: I have "Using nvidia binary driver 340.96 (open source)", but I don't have "Using nvidia binary driver 340.96 (proprietary)". I believe you need to install it first, then using "additional drivers" to switch among drivers.

Comment: @kenpeter That's weird, there is no open-source binary driver from nvidia, they (nvidia corp) do not provide the source code. The open-source driver for nvidia gpu is the "xorg open-source driver / nouveau". If it says "binary 340.96", that is the one from nvidia. No need to download anything, the tool will do that for you.